# How to show kendo ui widget inside kendo ui template

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

How Can I Render Kendo widget  Inside template.
I was tried to create datePicker indide a template and show it on div.
Is something wrong this code 
http://dojo.telerik.com/UMINe

```
<body>
  <div id="indider"> </div>
  <script id="template-student" type="text/x-kendo-template">
      <h1> #= a # </h1>
      <input id="datePicker" />
  </script>

<script>
    $(()=>{
        $('#datePicker').kendoDatePicker();

        var template = kendo.template($("#template-student").html());
        var result = template({a:'this is my template'});  
        alert(result);
        $('#indider').html(result);
    });
</script>
</body>
```

cheers

Answer (score 2):

This line converts the selected element to a kendo DatePicker widget:

```
$('#datePicker').kendoDatePicker();
```

However at that point the template has not yet been rendered and applied to the #insider element. As a result, #datePicker does not yet exist so nothing happens as you observe. Simply move the line to the end of your script block, since at that point the #dataPicker element will exist and the DatePicker widget will render:

```
...
alert(result);
$('#indider').html(result);
$('#datePicker').kendoDatePicker();
```